# vi hangs on macos after upgrade to catalina

Tags: command-line, vi, macos-catalina

I just upgraded to Catalina.

If I try to vi a file from Terminal or Term2, once I type return, nothing happens.

I can hop in another terminal and ps and it seems it's running, but again, its just looks hung.

I've tried restarting.  No change.

Ideas?